# How can you share the same port between two apps in Windows?

Tags: windows, iis, networking, openvpn

On a Windows machine, I need two apps (specifically, IIS and OpenVPN) to make use of port 443 simultaneously. I know it can be done in Linux, but is there a way to do that in Windows?
Here is what I have tried:

1. I tried [TCP port split software](https://www.aggsoft.com/tcp-splitter/), but it did not work out for me.
2. I tried using [.net port sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/net-tcp-port-sharing), but that seems limited to WCF apps and will not work in my scenario.
3. Tried to find ways to separate HTTP traffic from anything else, and send those to OpenVPN (but could not find any good apps for that so far).

In short, how can this be solved? For instance, could we write a WCF application that would forward traffic to OpenVPN and IIS?

Comment: No, a port is basically a pointer to the process to which TCP sends the payload. TCP would have no way to determine which process among multiple processes should get the payload for a singe port. The is actually the purpose of a port: to let TCP work with multiple processes, and the port number tells TCP to which process it should send the payload.

Comment: Please check [this document](http://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/), it may be helpful to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @RonMaupin, but for instance .net port sharing manages to send the response to different processes, if they are based on WCF. Is there a way to forward those responses to non-WCF apps?

Comment: Thank you @HuryShen, I checked the link but it is limited to websites whereas I need to run a completely different app along with the website.

Comment: If the document provided above can't implement your requirement, I afraid it may not be possible to implement what you expect.